# Union all with group by in sql: not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

my stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Driverperformance] @Ecode     NVARCHAR(50), 
                                          @startdate DATETIME, 
                                          @enddate   DATETIME 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate + ' 00:01:00.000', 
                                120); 
      DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate + ' 23:23:59.000', 
                                120) 
      ; 

      SELECT e.ecode, 
             Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date, 
             e.ename, 
             Count(q.ecode)        CntEcode 
      FROM   employeemaster_tbl e 
             JOIN transaction_tbl q 
               ON e.ecode = q.ecode 
      WHERE  q.ecode = @Ecode 
             AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + '' 
             AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
      UNION 
      SELECT e.ecode, 
             Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date, 
             e.ename, 
             Count(q.delecode)     DelEcode 
      FROM   employeemaster_tbl e 
             JOIN transaction_tbl q 
               ON e.ecode = q.delecode 
      WHERE  q.delecode = @Ecode 
             AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + '' 
             AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
      GROUP  BY e.ecode, 
                e.ename, 
                Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) 
      ORDER  BY Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) 
  END
```

while executing this am getting error:

> Column 'EmployeeMaster_tbl.Ecode' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `GROUP BY` in the code segment before the `UNION`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Driverperformance] @Ecode     NVARCHAR(50), 
                                          @startdate DATETIME, 
                                          @enddate   DATETIME 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate + ' 00:01:00.000', 
                                120); 
      DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate + ' 23:23:59.000', 
                                120) 
      ; 

      SELECT e.ecode, 
             Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date, 
             e.ename, 
             Count(q.ecode)        CntEcode 
      FROM   employeemaster_tbl e 
             JOIN transaction_tbl q 
               ON e.ecode = q.ecode 
      WHERE  q.ecode = @Ecode 
             AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + '' 
             AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + ''
      GROUP  BY e.ecode, 
                e.ename, 
                Cast(q.dtime AS DATE)              
      UNION 
      SELECT e.ecode, 
             Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date, 
             e.ename, 
             Count(q.delecode)     DelEcode 
      FROM   employeemaster_tbl e 
             JOIN transaction_tbl q 
               ON e.ecode = q.delecode 
      WHERE  q.delecode = @Ecode 
             AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + '' 
             AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + '' 
      GROUP  BY e.ecode, 
                e.ename, 
                Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) 
      ORDER  BY Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) 
  END
```

Raj

Comment: if i remove union i will get two results..actually i want to join this two results.. that s why i used union,

Comment: Unless you want DISTINCT results, you should use `UNION ALL`

Comment: i want to get result like this:

Comment: Ecode   Date         Ename    CntEcode   DelEcode
E003    2013-05-05   Raheem    4            3
E003    2013-05-27   Raheem    0            7
E003    2013-05-28   Raheem    1            1